# c# pass listview items from form to listview in another form

Tags: c#, sql, listview

I have form1 and form 2 .. and listview1 on form1 , listview2 on form2 when listview1 in form1 and listview2 in form2 and both listview contain : itemcode - itemcount . and button1 in form2

on form2 if user click button1 values in listview2 on form2 be populated in listview1 on form1 and form2 close
how to do such action in code
thanks

Comment: Stack overflow works by providing code you tried and where you got stuck not just asking for the answer. 

I saw this question in another form by a different user. Is this a homework assignment. Or did you create a new account and ask the same question?

Comment: can u give me a link to this question plz

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can do is parse listview into object and pass them across forms by passing objects in Forms constructors.

so in form1:

```
var form1LV = listView1;
    OnButton2Click(..){
    Form2 f = new Form2(form1LV);
..
}
```

and in form2's constructor

```
Form2(object f1LV){
Form1LV = (ListView)f1LV;
}
```

and then assign Form1LV to listView2 in form2.

```
listView2 = Form1LV on button click.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I want to remind u that I have only button1 which is on form1 and the user should populate listview1 on form1 with items in listview2 in form2 by clicking button1 on form2

Comment: Pass the object at the time of  initializing form 2 and use the object on button click on form 2